# command line perl to not clobber symbol links

Tags: command-line-interface, perl

I want to edit the original files with perl, when I have a numeric sequence of aliases.

The task is to use perl on the command line, e.g.

```
 perl -pe 's/apples/oranges/'
```

But to edit files in place:

```
 perl -i.bak
```

The `-i` option does not work with symbolic links

```
 ln -s fs fruitSalad
```

With `-i`, perl will re-write a new file, replacing (clobbering) the prior symbolic link. i.e. it does not edit original.

There's a workaround (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9318/is-there-a-way-to-make-perl-i-not-clobber-symlinks) which is like this:

```
 perl -i.bak -pe 's/apples/oranges/' $(readlink fs)
```

**Here's my problem**. I want to edit in-place, the original files from a sequence of symbolic links.

```
 ln -s fs.1 fruitSalad-1
 ln -s fs.2 fruitSalad-2
```

With normal files, perl will work with ranges, e.g.

```
 perl -i.bak -pe 's/apples/oranges/' fs.{1..2}
```

But that does not work with the `$(readlink __)` trick. 
It's not possible to combine the above, and I prefer to avoid xargs.

Any idea how to edit ranges of files via their symbolic links from the command line? What am I missing?

Comment: Here's an example with xargs....  seq 1 10 | xargs -n 1 -I % readlink %.xml | xargs -I % perl -pe 's#apples#oranges#ge' %

Answer (score 1):

One method is to replace the contents of `@ARGV` (the filenames being acted on) with the target of the link prior to looping over the file contents should that file be a symbolic link.

```
$ mkdir blah && cd blah
$ echo aa > orig
$ ln -s orig slink
$ perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{@ARGV=map{$_=readlink if -l}@ARGV}; s/aa/bb/' slink
$ readlink slink
orig
$ cat orig
bb
$
```